# Running remote commands on Windows like ssh -c on linux

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, remote

Is there a way to run remote commands in a windows system just like you can in Linux using the  "ssh -c" command.

Thanks!

Autobyte

Answer (score 7):

PSTools PSExec can do exactly that! :)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx

Comment: Does it have to be installed on each system that needs to be controlled or just the main server?  Also this only runs on a windows box right?  -- I guess this could work..

Comment: Just on the system you're using it from. And yes, win only.

Answer (score 2):

You can uses [powershell remoting](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2008/05/10/remoting-with-powershell-quickstart.aspx).  Psexec often gets blocked by antivirus.  Powershell remoting would be the most reliable way of performing remote commands.

Answer (score 1):

I have [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed on most of my Windows machines. With it's OpenSSH port you can use `ssh` just as your can to any Linux/BSD/*other* machine.

If you don't want anything else that Cygwin offers [copssh](http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh) seems a popular alternative - it is basically just the OpenSSH port and its dependences extracted from Cygwin.

The pstools set (already mentioned by northirid in an earlier answer) are easier to setup if windows->windows is all you need but actually having a SSH service is very handy if you need a little more.

Answer (score 0):

AT command is another way.

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of PSexec is that it executes and if required, copies the files to run on the destination system and can use any credentials

Answer (score 0):

From Unix / Linux, you have :

- cmdat, which comes with Samba-TNG
- winexe, http://eol.ovh.org/winexe/

Answer (score 0):

winrs (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/winrs), does what you need. It is a built-in command so you don't need anything extra. But first you need to run 'winrm quickconfig' on the remote machine (just once) for it to work.